Change site name
I can’t change the site name, I tried adding a tag
   <meta property="og:site_name" content="sitename">   
tried schema.org
    <head>
      <script type="application/ld+json">
        {JSON.stringify({
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type": "WebSite",
          "url": "https://sitename.com",
          "name": "sitename",
          "description": "description",
          "image": "https://sitename.com/logo_small.png",
        })}
      </script>
      <link rel="canonical" href="https://sitename.com"/>
    </head>

none of this helped, instead of the site name it just shows a link to it
it's about displaying the site name as it appears as you type, example:

for example, here the site name is displayed correctly (X Twitter), in my case a link is displayed instead of the name (as if in the case of Twitter it was displayed (https://twitter.com/instagram)

i use nextjs so without JSON.stringify it wouldn`t work

What output were you expecting here?  It's not clear to me.

Not sure if this might be your issue, but from docs, We recommend using next/script in your component instead of manually creating a <script> in next/head.   https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/head
